# ASP.NET Linkbutton not firing click event

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I click on the linkbutton nothing fires. Here is the code:

```
 protected void AccessFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        App_Code.bi.LogFileDownload("Access Fact Sheet", Session["UserID"].ToString());

    }
```

### html

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="AccessLink" runat="server" OnClick="AccessFile_Click" OnCommand="AccessLink_Command" Text="<img src='img/pdf_icon.png' border='0' />"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: What is OnCommand doing?

Comment: Take out the OnCommand attribute.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are you building this button dynamically?

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript/jQuery that might be intercepting the click?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out, somehow there were 2 form tags....... :(